# Change of itinerary After Getting the UK Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK Visitor Visa and got my Visa today, but there is change in itinerary as the meeting I was supposed to attend is at Feb 7, 2018 and it happens every month on 7th, but due to some urgent work at office I will not be able to go to the UK on my provided dates. In fact, I will be attending the same meet up on March 7th and will stay for the around same duration.

I have seen some refusal letter where even within the given visa validity ECO has raised the question about change of plan or stayed more than planned.

Will that effects my future applications or is should I inform UKVI about this change of plan?

Comment: Just carry evidence along and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's not going to be a problem unless the premise of the entire trip changes.

Comment: +1 The cases I've seen here that led to serious trouble had an actual itinerary for which it would have been harder to get a visa, leading to a suspicion of deception in the original application.

Comment: yeah I believe so is there any channel or mode where I can report this change of itinerary in order to make sure that I acted as a responsible citizen and I have no motives of deception or anything!